# PHP Mysql - exporting whole database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, export

I would like the administrator on my website to give the option to export the whole database of the website on one click, just a simple submit button which will save the database in .csv or sql to the PC, is this possible at all?

Comment: mysqldump is what you want. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to stream the output of the `mysqldump` command using [passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).  If you set the proper headers the output can be downloadable.

Comment: I am not sure how this works, I have looked at the site but is this a function or different software?

Comment: mysqldump is part of the mysql installation.  If you've installed mysql then you have mysqldump.  It takes a few parameters like username, password, and database to connect to, among other things.

Answer (score 3):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'your_table.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM your_table
```

Or use navicat (software)
good luck

**Thanks @Crashspeeder**

```
mysqldump database_name > database_name.sql
```

navicat tool remains a solution

Comment: That's only one table, though.  He wants the whole database.

Comment: How does this actually work? I am not sure how mysql dump works is there any script connected to a button that will just make the whole database downloadable?